# In Delphi connecting to a database in runtime

Tags: delphi

I'm busy with a project where the database must be embedded in such way that if it should be copied over to any computer you can run it without establishing the connection to the database again. I have tried this :

```
path:=extractFilePath('MEDA_p.exe');
dmMEDA.conMeda.ConnectionString:='Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= '+path+'dbMEDA.accdb; Persist Security info=false';
dmMEDA.conMeda.Connected:=true;
```

But keep getting 'Stack overflow' errors. Or if I Do this:

```
dmMeda.conMEDA.open;
path:=extractFilePath('MEDA_p.exe');
dmMEDA.conMeda.ConnectionString:='Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= '+path+'dbMEDA.accdb; Persist Security info=false';
dmMEDA.conMeda.Connected:=true;
dmMEDA.conMeda.close;
```

I get 'Operation is not allowed when the object is open'.

Any help?

## Update:

I have tried some of the suggestions, like adding double quotes and using connection and setting it false then afterward true, but when I try and make the tables (active) true I get another 'Stack overflow error'

```
dmMEDA.tbllogs.Active:=true;
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you opened the connection in the IDE? If so, set it to active = false in the IDE before you run the program.

Comment: I don't know what that path variable is for, but if you're intending to use it as a path to writeable data, it's an accident waiting to happen.  Don't assume you can write to the folder where the app is located.

Answer (score 2):

Your sequence of events is wrong in the second block. You need to close the connection, make the change, and then open the connection again.

```
dmMeda.conMEDA.Connected := False;
path:=extractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
dmMEDA.conMeda.ConnectionString:='Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= '+path+'dbMEDA.accdb; Persist Security info=false';
dmMEDA.conMeda.Connected:=true;
```

Note that if the path to the application can contain spaces, you may need to surround it with double quotes as well.

```
dmMeda.conMEDA.Connected := False;
path := extractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
dmMEDA.conMeda.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= "' + path + 'dbMEDA.accdb"; Persist Security info=false';
dmMEDA.conMeda.Connected := True;
```

Comment: The path does require double quotes, I've had such an issue in the past.